# make .desktop execute at startup before login

Tags: login, cron, .desktop

I want to make a python script run automatically with Ubuntu startup. The script requires a specific environment and other stuff, which was easier to run using .desktop. Now the .desktop file works perfectly after logging in.

I wonder if it is possible to make the script run before login? (preferably run as the user)

If not, what is the standard way to do so?

I know maybe using crontab is more of a common way to do so. But I had trouble making the script work OK to do several resource access(and maybe dependencies) required by the script. (It runs but does not perform the job)

Comment: I don't know about making it run as the user, but you can copy your .desktop file to the `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder as that will make it launch before anyone logs in.

Comment: A great way to run a script automatically is to use a systemd unit. They are very easy to setup, a quick google search will produce plenty of articles describing how to do it and you can get very fine control over when they run.

Comment: I don't think you can launch as a user before the user is logged in.  Once a user logs out of a system all applications that are owned by the user are closed.  You might want to look into installing what you need as the root user which is always available.